# Error while installing 'bundle install' in kali linux

Tags: ruby, linux, installation, bundle, bundler

An error occurred while installing xmlrpc (0.3.2), and Bundler
cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
xmlrpc

Comment: Please, post all information you have, like the error message and all the log generated by that error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run

```
gem install xmlrpc
```

and for every gem the same, like

```
gem install unf
```